# How can I insert data into multiple columns using one query with a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo

I have an associative array that inserts each 'key' and 'value' into my database table. At the moment an individual query runs for each key ***for each iteration*** of the loop, however I want it to grab each 'key' and 'element', and insert them as pairs in ***one*** query.

PHP:

```
$elements = array(
    'column_1' => 'data1',
    'column_2' => 'data2',
    'column_3' => 'data3'
);

foreach($elements as $key=>$value) {
    $key = $key;
    $value = $value;

    DB::query('INSERT INTO `table` (' . $key . ') VALUES (?);', array($value));
}
```

Comment: You have to bind the param to the question mark.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you please explain?

Comment: I've posted an example below

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sprintf()` to decide what columns you want to insert, for example:
`sprintf("INSERT INTO '%s' ('%s', '%s') VALUES ('%s', '%s')", $array[tableName], $array[col1name], $array[col2name], $array[col1val], $array[col2val]);`

I hope this is the kind of thing that you are looking for?

Comment: also it needs to be a loop because I have a number of generated array elements

Comment: You loop out the return, for example 
`$qry = sprintf();

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
/*    Do work on array retrurned     */
}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use foreach to create your query. You can use combination of `implode()`, `array_keys()` and `array_values()` functions:

```
$elements = array(
    'column_1' => 'data1',
    'column_2' => 'data2',
    'column_3' => 'data3'
);

$fieldNames = array_keys($elements));
$fieldsQueryPart = '`' . implode('`, `', $fieldNames . '`';
$valuesQueryPart = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($fieldNames), '?'));
$values = array_values($elements);

DB::query('INSERT INTO `table` (' . $fieldsQueryPart . ') VALUES (' . $valuesQueryPart . ');', $values);
```

---

*EDIT:*
Because I think you are using plain `PDO`, so your `DB::query()` line should be replaced. You have to first create `PDO` object:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Then you need to prepare statement:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `table` (' . $fieldsQueryPart . ') VALUES (' . $valuesQueryPart . ');');
```

Last two steps is to bind values to query and execute it or just execute passing values to `execute()` method

```
$statement->execute($values);
```

OR

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $statement->bindValue($key + 1, $value);
}
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: @mightyspaj3 It's `query()` standard `PDO::query()` or it's your own method?

Comment: I need to use my DB::query, I have an OOP system that requires it

Comment: There is an error => `$fieldNames = array_keys($elements));` should be `$fieldNames = array_keys($elements);` and  ```$fieldsQueryPart = '`' . implode('`, `', $fieldNames . '`';``` should be => ```$fieldsQueryPart = '`' . implode('`, `', $fieldNames) . '`';```

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use like this:

```
$columns = implode(", ", array_keys($elements));
$values  = implode(", ", array_values($elements));
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
$fields = '';
foreach($elements as $col => $val) {
      if ($count++ != 0) 
   $fields .= ', ';
      $col = mysql_real_escape_string($col);
      $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
      $fields .= "`$col` = $val";
   }

   $query = "INSERT INTO `table` SET $fields";
```

try this...

Comment: how is that supposed to work if the fields reset with each iteration, I want all values and keys to be inserted in one query

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way

```
$columns = implode(", ", array_keys($elements));
$escaped = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($elements));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Comment: what can I replace with MySQL_real_escape_string? I'm using a prepared statement so I don't need it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, here's an example:
The question mark can be an array of values, so each question mark should be binded to a value.

```
    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

        $this->_error = false;

        if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {

            $x = 1;

            if (count($params)) {

                foreach ($params as $param) {

                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);

                    $x++;

                }

            }

            if ($this->_query->execute()) {

                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();

            } else {

                $this->_error = true;

            }

        } else {

            $this->_error = true;

        }

        return $this;

    }
```